# how to convert surface to vector field to use it in line integral

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

example for what i want to say how to convert the scalar form of line integral :-
$\int g(x,y)\ ds = \int p\ dx + \int q\ dy$

real world example:-

$\int xy \ ds \ s: unit \ circle \ centered at origin$

to

$ \int p\ dx + \int q\ dy $

Comment: Use Green's theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html

Comment: thanks but actually i know that quiet but what iwant to know is is there is away of converting between scalar and vector notation or not even if it's hard or not is there a way or not ??

Answer (score 0):

The unit circle centered at the origin is given by parametric equations $x= \cos(t), y= \sin(t)$ with $t$ going from 0 to $2\pi$ so $dx= -\sin(t)dt$ and $dy= \cos(t)dt$. $ds^2= (dx)^2+ (dy)^2$ so $ds= \sqrt{(dx)^2+ (dy)^2}= \sqrt{(-\sin(t)dt)^2+ (\cos(t)dt)^2}= \sqrt{\sin^2(t)+ \cos^2(t)}dt= dt$.  (More simply, the angle t, measured in **radians**, measures the circumference of the circle.  With "t" in radians, $ds= dt$).

$\int xy ds= \int_0^{2\pi} cos(t)dt$.

There is no $\int dx+ dy$.

Comment: this means that i cannot convert scalar form to vector form ??